# Go pipe write end being closed, why?

Tags: linux, go

I just read some Go code that does something along the following lines:

```
type someType struct {
    ...
    ...
    rpipe io.ReadCloser
    wpipe io.WriteCloser
}

var inst someType

inst.rpipe, inst.wpipe, _ := os.Pipe()
cmd := exec.Command("some_binary", args...)
cmd.Stdout = inst.wpipe
cmd.Stderr = inst.wpipe
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    ....
}
inst.wpipe.Close()
inst.wpipe = nil
```

`some_binary` is a long running process.

1. Why is `inst.wpipe` closed and set to nil? What would happen if its not closed? Is it common/necessary to close inst.wpipe?
2. Is `dup2(pipe_fd[1], 1)` the C analogue of `cmd.Stdout = inst.wpipe; inst.wpipe.Close()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo. Let me fix it. Both stdout and stderr and set to wpipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is typical of a program that wants to read output generated by some other program.  The [`os.Pipe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Pipe) function returns a connected pair of `os.File` entities (or, on error—which should not be simply ignored—doesn't) where a write on the second (`w` or `wpipe`) entity shows up as readable bytes on the first (`r` / `rpipe`) entity.  But—this is the key to half the answer to your first question—how will a reader know when all writers are finished writing?

For a reader to get an EOF indication, *all* writers that have or had access to the write side of the pipe *must* call the `close` operation.  By passing the write side of the pipe to a program that we start with `cmd.Start()`, we allow that command to access the write side of the pipe.  When that command closes that pipe, one of the entities with access has closed the pipe.  But another entity with access hasn't closed it yet: *we* have write access.

To see an EOF, then, *we* must close off access to *our* `wpipe`, with `wpipe.Close()`.  So that answer the first half of:

> 1. Why is `inst.wpipe` closed and set to nil?

The set-to-`nil` part may or may not have any function; you should inspect the rest of the code to find out if it does.

> 2. Is `dup2(pipe_fd[1], 1)` the C analogue of `cmd.Stdout = inst.wpipe; inst.wpipe.Close()?`

Not precisely.  The `dup2` level is down in the POSIX OS area, while `cmd.Stdout` is at a higher (OS-independent) level.  The POSIX implementation of `cmd.Start()` will wind up calling `dup2` (or something equivalent) like this after calling `fork` (or something equivalent).  The POSIX equivalent of `inst.wipe.Close()` is `close(wfd)` where `wfd` is the POSIX file number in `wpipe`.

In C code that doesn't have any higher level wrapping around it, we'd have something like:

```c
int fds[2];

if (pipe(fds) < 0) ... handle error case ...
pid = fork();
switch (pid) {
case -1: ... handle error ...

case 0: /* child */
    if (dup2(fds[1], 1) < 0 || dup2(fds[1], 2) < 0) ... handle error ...
    if (execve(prog, args, env) < 0) ... handle error ...
    /* NOTREACHED */

default: /* parent */
    if (close(fds[1]) < 0) ... handle error ...
    ... read from fds[0] ...
}
```

(although if we're careful enough to check for an error from `close`, we probably should be careful enough to check whether the `pipe` system call gave us back descriptors 0 and 1, or 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, here—though perhaps we handle this earlier by making sure that 0, 1, and 2 are at least open to `/dev/null`).